# Stanford OpenIE: How to output dependency path instead of plain text patterns?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am looking through the Java source code and wondering if it's easy to modify the system such that the predicate portion of each triple is the dependency path between the two entities instead of the surface form.

Since the natural logic module operates on the dependency trees I suppose there shall be an easy tweak to this demand.

I trace the code in edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli/OpenIE.java to:

```
// Get the extractions
boolean empty = true;
synchronized (OUTPUT) {
  for (CoreMap sentence : ann.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
    for (RelationTriple extraction : sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class)) {
      // Print the extractions
      OUTPUT.println(tripleToString(extraction, docid, sentence));
      empty = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Please point me to the implementation of the following step:

```
sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each relation triple actually does store the dependency structure from which it was generated. Take a look at the [`asDependencyTree()` function](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/util/RelationTriple.java#L460) in [`RelationTriple`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/util/RelationTriple.java).

Note that this tree is not necessarily a subtree of the original sentence -- e.g., it may be that a subject was moved around to produce a relation triple. If you're looking for a dependency path in the original sentence, you can look up tokens by their `IndexAnnotation` and compute a dependency path from that.

Comment: A follow up question: is there an option to output lemmatized pattern, e.g. "was born in" to "is bear in", "married to" to "marry to", etc.?

Comment: W.r.t the follow up above presumably we could replace word on the relation triple to their lemmas.

Comment: Solved: use the "extraction.relationLemmaGloss()" function!